# Separate strings in columns in a dataframe with delimiter and adding sub-strings in to separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

Originally my question was:

I have dataframe for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                "EmailAdds": ["pamelasilvera@gmail.com"],
                "Subject": ["Report submission", "Meeting update"]
            })
```

I wanted to separate the email IDs int the column `"EmailAdds"` based on "@" and have to addition columns having the root email ID and the domain name. The final dataframe was supposed to look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    "EmailAdds": ["pamelasilvera@gmail.com"],
                    "Subject": ["Report submission", "Meeting update"]
                })
```

Later I realized that the column `"EmailAdds"` can have multiple emails in one row of data separated by ";". Actually my dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            "EmailAdds": ["pamelasilvera@gmail.com; adarandall@gmail.com; larryjacob@orange.com", "indiejesse.d@gmail.com"],
            "Subject": ["Report submission", "Meeting update"]
        })
```

What I really want to do is:

I want to go through each element of `"EmailAdds"` and at first separate the emails using ';' then separate each email address using @ into substrings then add 2 more columns first `"EmailAdd_roots"` containing the substrings of the email addresses of that row let's say "pamelasilvera adarandall larryjacob" and second `"EmailAdd_domains"` containing unique domain names without ".com" let's "gmail orange".

The resulting dataframe should look exactly like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                "EmailAdds": ["pamelasilvera@gmail.com; adarandall@gmail.com; larryjacob@orange.com", "indiejesse.d@gmail.com"],
                "Subject": ["Report submission", "Meeting update"],
                "EmailAdds_roots": ["pamelasilvera adarandall larryjacob", "indiejesse"],
                "EmailAdds_domains":["gmail orange", "gmail"]
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mouthfull:

```
emails = df['EmailAdds'].str.split(';').explode()
df = df.join(
         emails.str.split('@', expand=True) \
         .fillna('') \
         .groupby(level=0) \
         .agg(
             { 0: ' '.join,
               1: lambda x: ' '.join(set(x))}
         ).rename(columns=['EmailAdds_roots', 'EmailAdds_domains'].__getitem__)
     )
```

Results:

```
          EmailAdds            Subject  \
0  pamelasilvera@gmail.com; adarandall@gmail.com;...  Report submission   
1                             indiejesse.d@gmail.com     Meeting update   

                         EmailAdds_roots     EmailAdds_domains  
0  pamelasilvera  adarandall  larryjacob  gmail.com orange.com  
1                           indiejesse.d             gmail.com
```

---

An alternative, more readable version would be:

```
emails = df['EmailAdds'].str.split(';').explode() \
            .str.split('@', expand=True).fillna('') \
            .groupby(level=0)
df['EmailAdds_roots'] = emails[0].agg(list).str.join(' ')
df['EmailAdds_domains'] = emails[1].unique().str.join(' ')
```

Comment: Okay, I tried this. But the problem is some of the values in the 'EmailAdd' column contain np.nan values because they are empty. So, on doing the above I get an error. How do I avoid this error?

Comment: Updated answer with `fillna`, give that a try?

Comment: ahh okay. So, seems like it solved that np.nan issue but another thing is my dataframe contains many columns and "EmailAdds" is in the middle. I want the new columns right after "EmailAdds" but now I am getting an index error.

Comment: You can reorder your columns after the `join` operation.  `df = df.loc[:, list_of_column_names_in_desired_ordder]`

Comment: Wait actually fillna didn't work. I was mistaken. It shows this error sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found"

Comment: I thought that error was due to sequence of the columns or something. But actually I think its because of the "NoneType".

Comment: Did you try the updated `fillna` that's in the answer? The original comment I made didn't handle it fully. thus I removed it.  The `fillna` in the second `split` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

We do `join` with `str.split`

```
df=df.join(df.EmailAdd.str.split('@',expand=True))
Out[138]: 
                  EmailAdd            Subject              0          1
0  pamelasilvera@gmail.com  Report submission  pamelasilvera  gmail.com
1   indiejesse.d@gmail.com     Meeting update   indiejesse.d  gmail.com
```

Comment: But I want the separated strings to be in named columns such as "Email" , "Domain". Not "0" or "1"

Comment: Also, I think my example was a bad one. I forgot to mention that there can be multiple emails in one columns separated by ";" .  From that columns I just want 2 new columns one containing only the email roots separated by ";" and another one containing the unique domain names separated by ";".

Comment: @IndySupertramp `df.join(df.EmailAdd.str.split('@',expand=True).rename(columns={0 : 'Email',1:'domain'}))`

Comment: Please look at my second message.

Comment: Hello! I just edited the question. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `str.extract` with a named regex groups:

```
df.join(df.EmailAdd.str.extract('^(?P<Email>[^@]+)@(?P<Domain>.+)'))
```

Output:

```
                  EmailAdd            Subject          Email     Domain
0  pamelasilvera@gmail.com  Report submission  pamelasilvera  gmail.com
1   indiejesse.d@gmail.com     Meeting update   indiejesse.d  gmail.com
```